# Simple C++11 Subject-Observer

Tags: c++, c++11, callback, observer-pattern

Building on the answer in [C++ class member callback simple examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189440/c-class-member-callback-simple-examples), I've tried to put together a simple subject-observer pattern without needing to inherit a virtual Observer class. I also wanted to isolate most of the C++11 funny stuff within the Subject. `bind` and `function` are little-used features, so keeping the number of uses low should reduce opportunities for programmer errors.

Example class name `Subject`. Callback for this example takes one `bool` argument. In `Subject` declaration:

```
public:
    template<class T> void addCallback(T* object, void(T::*mf)(bool))
    {
        callbacks_.emplace_back(std::bind(mf, object, std::placeholders::_1));
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::function<void(bool)>> callbacks_;
```

In `Observer` declaration (class name for example `Observer`):

```
    void nameDoesntMatter(bool);
```

In `Subject` implementation, to call observers:

```
for (const auto& cb: callbacks_)
    cb(booleanValue);
```

In `Observer` implementation, to register callback, assuming `sub` points to the `Subject` class in question:

```
sub->addCallback(this, &Observer::nameDoesntMatter);
```

Seems pretty simple. Seems to work ok.

Questions:

1. How can I alter this so that an observer can remove its registration with the subject?
2. If I'm worried about speed, is there a significant difference between the traditional virtual base class implementation of this pattern and the one described here?
3. Did I make a mistake in my implementation?